# HTML: span with a background color and image -- why doesn't the color appear under the image?

Tags: css, image, html

I'm trying to add an arrow image beside the text within a span. Here's the HTML I'm working with:

```
<span id="status" class='unreviewed'>
  Unreviewed 
  <img src="bullet_arrow_down.png" />
</span>
```

Now, I've coloured the background of the span with this css:

```
#status {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-background-clip:border;
  -moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
  -moz-background-origin:padding;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  top: 10px;
}

#status span.unreviewed {
  padding: 3px 4px; 
  background:#DA704B none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

#status span.unreviewed img {
  float: right;
}
```

Now, this displays everything correctly lined up, but the background colour doesn't extend past the end of the word "Unreviewed". The image, despite being a transparent png, is white behind, rather than #DA704B.

This is the case with both Firefox and Safari. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Spans need to have display: block; in order to work like that.

```
#status {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-background-clip:border;
  -moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
  -moz-background-origin:padding;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Honestly you should probably just switch the <span> to a <div> that way you conform to the spec properly and your code will inherently work.

Answer (score 2):

Well, What jumps out at me is:

```
#status span.unreviewed
```

would be the selector for span with class "unreviewed" that is a *descendant* of #status. The selector you are looking for is

```
#status.unreviewed
```

You might want to have a look at the w3c specifications for CSS2 to avoid selector problems like this. 
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Hope that helps.

edit: one other quick point, why not use `background-color` instead of `background` as all you're doing is changing the background color?

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
#status span.unreviewed {
```

to
    span.unreviewed {

that works for me in all browsers.

If it still doesn't work, try making it block-level or use a div, as the colouring doesn't quite work as you'd expect on inline elements

Answer (score 0):

You might also find it worthwhile declaring:

```
#status span.unreviewed img {
background-color: transparent;
}
```

that should at least remove the white default image background.